# Mobile Native app testing (IOS & Android)

Tags: android, ios, frameworks, performance-testing, ios-ui-automation

Please let me know if there is any tool available for 
1. Mobile Native app(IOS & Android) testing for UI or functional tool
2. Mobile native app testing(IOS & Android) for Performance or load
3. test framework for Native app testing such as Appium

Comment: please provide details related to IOS native app as per the priority.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Robotium to automaye your UI test cases. 
Check here

https://code.google.com/p/robotium/

For performance testing you should use Monkey Runner tool.It is provided with the Android sdk

Answer (score 0):

[Appium](http://www.Appium.io) is probably the way you want to go. It allows you to write the tests in a huge variety of languages and is cross platform.

It uses the same code base to write tests for Android and iOS which is a huge benefit since you don't have to train QA (who generally end up writing these tests) in two different code bases.

Also, Appium has an inspector which generates code for you as you perform your test manually so it can easily be learned and used by people who don't have much coding experience.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using appium [Appium.io](http://appium.io.) right now for Android and iOS testing and found it pretty easy to use for UI/functional testing.

Our setup is Appium framework + java + cucumber to manager the UI testing.

Not sure what else you're looking for with this question.